# How can I use XMRig to connect to monerod

Tags: monerod, mining, xmrig

I have a node running monerod. And have many nodes to run XMRig. How can I start monerod in order to connect XMRig?

Comment: If you are looking to solo mine with XMRig, here is a starting point:  https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig/blob/master/scripts/solo_mine_example.cmd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I use XMRig to connect monerod...

Set the *pool URL* to your local daemon (i.e. `127.0.0.1:18081`), the *user* to your wallet address and set `daemon:true` (in the config file), or `--daemon` (as a command-line argument).

So if using a config file, then like:

```
{
    "cpu": true,
    "pools": [
        {
            "algo": "rx/0",
            "coin": "monero",
            "url": "127.0.0.1:18081",
            "user": "48ed...",
            "daemon": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Of if using command-line arguments, like:

```
./xmrig -o 127.0.0.1:18081 -a rx/0 -u 48ed... --daemon
```

> How can I start monerod...

For starting `monerod`, you don't need any specific settings for localhost connections from XMRig (as used like above).

If however you intend to connect instances of XMRig *not* running localhost to the daemon, you will need to adjust the above pool IP to that of the IP you will run `monerod` on, and start `monerod` with an appropriate `--rpc-bind-ip <your IP>` or `--rpc-restricted-bind-ip <your IP>`.

Comment: May I set the wallet address on monerod, not on XMRig?

Comment: No, if you want to use XMRig for mining using a daemon, you must configure as I have answered.

Comment: How can I see the XMRig connections on the monerod?

Comment: "How can I see the XMRig connections on the monerod?" <- Increase your daemon log level, e.g. `set_log +daemon.rpc:INFO`, or compile XMRig with `WITH_DEBUG_LOG`, or use a tool like tcpdump.

Comment: The XMRig show ' net      use pool donate.v2.xmrig.com:3333  178.128.242.134'. Is this right?

Comment: "Is this right?" <- No. That is using the donate pool. See config in the answer. If you used the config from above, you'd see `net use daemon 127.0.0.1:18081  127.0.0.1`.